# Reference trough null FORTRAN pointer main

Tags: fortran

My program compiles fine but when I run it, it says  :

```
error: reference trough null FORTRAN pointer main -  in file matrix-2dim.f90 at line 31 [+0a6f]
```

Where is the problem? I printed every variable to make sure everything works fine and it seems alright but I can't identify this error.

edit: compiler is gnu fortan 8.2.0 and I'm using Plato ide also tried simply Fortran with GCC compiler didn't work either
edit2: the input file is here:https://gofile.io/d/QHL0EH

```
program input
    implicit none
    real:: A,E,L,S,x1,y1,x2,y2,sinn,coss
    integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
    real,allocatable::kt(:,:),k(:,:),ktt(:,:),dx(:),forcee(:)&
    ,D(:),T1(:,:),cousin(:),sinus(:),TT(:,:),aa(:,:),b(:,:),c(:,:),kk(:,:),f(:),bb(:,:),lt(:),elastycity(:),dd(:),stress(:),ELAA(:)
 

    open(unit=12,file='data.txt',action='read')
    open(unit=20,file='out.txt')
    read(12,*) ne
    write(*,*)'number of elements',ne
    read(12,*) n
    write(*,*)'number of nodes   ',n
    allocate(kt(2*n,2*n)),k(4,4),ktt(8,8),forcee(2*n),D(2*n),T1(6,6),cousin(3),sinus(3),TT(8,8),aa(8,8),b(8,8),c(8,8),kk(8,8),f(8),bb(8,8),ELAA(3),lt(3),elastycity(3),dd(8),stress(3))
   
    kt(:,:)=0
   
    do p=1,ne
        
    read(12,*) x1,y1,x2,y2,ss,ee,E,A
    write(*,*)'============================================================='
    write(*,*) 'element',p
    L=(((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
    write(*,*)
    write(*,*)'L=    ',L
    s=(A*E)/(L)
    write(*,*)
    write(*,*)'s=     ',s

    cousin(p)=(x2-x1)/L
    sinus(p)=(y2-y1)/L
    coss=cousin(p)
    sinn=sinus(p)
    write(*,*)
    write(*,*)'cos=   ',cousin(p)
    write(*,*)
    write(*,*)'sin=   ',sinus(p)
    write(*,*)   
    
   
    k(1,1)=(coss**2)*s
    
    k(1,2)=(coss*sinn)*s
    
    k(2,1)=(coss*sinn)*s
    
    k(2,2)=(sinn**2)*s
  
    k(1,3)=-k(1,1)
    
    k(1,4)=-k(1,2)
    
    k(2,3)=-k(2,1)
    
    k(2,4)=-k(2,2)
  
    k(3,1)=-k(1,1)
    
    k(3,2)=-k(1,2)
    
    k(4,1)=-k(2,1)
    
    k(4,2)=-k(2,2)
    
    k(3,3)=k(1,1)
    
    k(3,4)=k(1,2)
    
    k(4,3)=k(2,1)
    
    k(4,4)=k(2,2)
    
     
 
    
   kt(2*ss-1,2*ss-1)=kt(2*ss-1,2*ss-1)+k(1,1)
    kt(2*ss-1,2*ss)=kt(2*ss-1,2*ss)+k(1,2)
    kt(2*ss-1,2*ee-1)=kt(2*ss-1,2*ee-1)+k(1,3)
    kt(2*ss-1,2*ee)=kt(2*ss-1,2*ee)+k(1,4)
    kt(2*ss,2*ss-1)=kt(2*ss,2*ss-1)+k(2,1)
    kt(2*ss,2*ss)=kt(2*ss,2*ss)+k(2,2)
    kt(2*ss,2*ee-1)=kt(2*ss,2*ee-1)+k(2,3)
    kt(2*ss,2*ee)=kt(2*ss,2*ee)+k(2,4)
    kt(2*ee-1,2*ss-1)=kt(2*ee-1,2*ss-1)+k(3,1)
    kt(2*ee-1,2*ss)=kt(2*ee-1,2*ss)+k(3,2)
    kt(2*ee-1,2*ee-1)=kt(2*ee-1,2*ee-1)+k(3,3)
    kt(2*ee-1,2*ee)=kt(2*ee-1,2*ee)+k(3,4)
    kt(2*ee,2*ss-1)=kt(2*ee,2*ss-1)+k(4,1)
    kt(2*ee,2*ss)=kt(2*ee,2*ss)+k(4,2)
    kt(2*ee,2*ee-1)=kt(2*ee,2*ee-1)+k(4,3)
    kt(2*ee,2*ee)=kt(2*ee,2*ee)+k(4,4)
    
    do jj=1,4
  write(*,*)k(jj,:)
 end do
    end do
   
  write(*,*)
  
  do jj=1,6
  write(*,*)kt(jj,:)
  end do
   
 
 
   end
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour].  If you have an error message, you have to show us the exact code that generated the error. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Especially, we need to see the declaration of your variables and arrays. We need to see how `X` and `Y` are declared. We need to see the whole `function` or `subroutine` or `program` or any other unit where you have these lines you show. We simply need to see much more code. we should be able to try to compile your complete example and get your error.

Comment: thanks, bro I fixed that . now I have a bigger problem and changed the post I would appreciate it if you take a look

Comment: You did not ask any question in your new post. Is there any problem with the code you posted? What is your question?

Comment: it seems that you were right. I really couldn't express my problem I adjusted it thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Your program requirs some data file. We cannot test your program without your data. Try to make a [mcve] that does not require any external data or just a small text file that you can copy and paste here. Use all debugving and error checking flags that your compiler has. Also, tell us what compiler version you are using.

Comment: here is the link to my input txt file 
```
https://gofile.io/d/QHL0EH
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for problems.

1. The `allocate` statement in line 13 closes right after the first variable.
2. The `allocate` statement in line 13 is too long and needs to be broken onto the next line by inserting newline character `&` before the `b` variable.
3. The given input file has an empty second line and therefor `kt` is of size `[0,0]` and throws an error when accessed.

---

The line 13 could be replaced by

```pascal
...
allocate (kt(2*n,2*n),k(4,4),ktt(8,8),forcee(2*n),D(2*n),T1(6,6),        &
  &       cousin(3),sinus(3),TT(8,8),aa(8,8),b(8,8),c(8,8),kk(8,8),f(8), &
  &       bb(8,8),ELAA(3),lt(3),elastycity(3),dd(8),stress(3)            )
...
```

---

Note that your code still throws warnings when compiling with debug flags.

```sh
$ gfortran -Wall -g3 -fcheck=all -fuse-ld=bfd a.f90 && ./a.out
a.f90:4:40:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                        1
Warning: Unused variable ‘dis’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:36:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                    1
Warning: Unused variable ‘diss’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:5:49:

    5 |   real,allocatable::kt(:,:),k(:,:),ktt(:,:),dx(:),forcee(:)&
      |                                                 1
Warning: Unused variable ‘dx’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:46:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                              1
Warning: Unused variable ‘force’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:25:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                         1
Warning: Unused variable ‘i’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:28:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                            1
Warning: Unused variable ‘ii’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:48:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                                1
Warning: Unused variable ‘j’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:54:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                                      1
Warning: Unused variable ‘kj’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
a.f90:4:51:

    4 |   integer::ne,p,n,ss,ee,i,ii,jj,diss,dis,force,j,xx,kj
      |                                                   1
Warning: Unused variable ‘xx’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
 number of elements           2
 number of nodes              3
 =============================================================
 element           1

 L=       10.0000000    

 s=        6000000.00    

 cos=      0.00000000    

 sin=      1.00000000    

   0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000000      -0.00000000    
   0.00000000       6000000.00      -0.00000000      -6000000.00    
  -0.00000000      -0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    
  -0.00000000      -6000000.00       0.00000000       6000000.00    
 =============================================================
 element           2

 L=       14.1421356    

 s=        4242640.50    

 cos=     0.707106769    

 sin=     0.707106769    

   2121320.00       2121320.00      -2121320.00      -2121320.00    
   2121320.00       2121320.00      -2121320.00      -2121320.00    
  -2121320.00      -2121320.00       2121320.00       2121320.00    
  -2121320.00      -2121320.00       2121320.00       2121320.00    

   2121320.00       2121320.00       0.00000000       0.00000000      -2121320.00      -2121320.00    
   2121320.00       8121320.00       0.00000000      -6000000.00      -2121320.00      -2121320.00    
   0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    
   0.00000000      -6000000.00       0.00000000       6000000.00       0.00000000       0.00000000    
  -2121320.00      -2121320.00       0.00000000       0.00000000       2121320.00       2121320.00    
  -2121320.00      -2121320.00       0.00000000       0.00000000       2121320.00       2121320.00
```

where I used the following `data.txt` file (note the `3` in line 2)

```
2 4 3 3 1
3
0 0 0 10 1 2 2 30e6
0 0 10 10 1 3 2 30e6
0 0 10 0 1 4 2 30e6
```

Comment: thanks a lot .the issue with kt was really killing me. I'm super new to coding and I have to do this for my project and this community is really helpful and generous with their knowledge